# Playing lands with Ugin's ultimate

Tags: magic-the-gathering

With [Ugin, the Spirit Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ugin%2C%20the%20Spirit%20Dragon)'s third ability, it says "Gain seven life, draw 7 cards, and place up to 7 permanents from your hand to the battlefield." Does this include land because land is a permanent, or is the "1 land per turn" rule still in effect?

Answer (score 13):

You can put lands onto the battlefield with Ugin's ability because you are not playing lands (a special action limited to once a turn) you are just putting them onto the battlefield.

> **115.2a** Playing a land is a special action. To play a land, a player puts that land onto the battlefield from the zone it was in (usually that player’s hand). By default, a player can take this action only once during each of his or her turns. A player can take this action any time he or she has priority and the stack is empty during a main phase of his or her turn.
>
> **305.4.** Effects may also allow players to “put” lands onto the battlefield. This isn’t the same as “playing a land” and doesn’t count as a land played during the current turn.